# Make image centered and responsive within a page with countdown

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a HTML page which contains a countdown and above it, I want to add an image, center it and make it responsive. I tried several ways, but it did not turn out to be responsive.
I want it to look like in this picture:

[image]

But if I resize the page, it looks like here (complete disaster) :

[image]

I tried to add "width: 100%", but the image turns out to be huge and this is why I have to use "width:20%". How can I make this image responsive (the countdown is, as you can see) ?

Below is my code:

```js
var target_date = new Date("January 20, 2020");
var days, hours, minutes, seconds; // variables for time units
var countdown = document.getElementById("tiles"); // get tag element
getCountdown();
setInterval(function() {
  getCountdown();
}, 1000);

function getCountdown() {
  // find the amount of "seconds" between now and target
  var current_date = new Date().getTime();
  var seconds_left = (target_date - current_date) / 1000;
  days = pad(parseInt(seconds_left / 86400));
  seconds_left = seconds_left % 86400;
  hours = pad(parseInt(seconds_left / 3600));
  seconds_left = seconds_left % 3600;
  minutes = pad(parseInt(seconds_left / 60));
  seconds = pad(parseInt(seconds_left % 60));
  // format countdown string + set tag value
  countdown.innerHTML = "<span>" + days + "</span><span>" + hours + "</span><span>" + minutes + "</span><span>" + seconds + "</span>";
}

function pad(n) {
  return (n < 10 ? '0' : '') + n;
}
```

```css
body {
  font: normal 13px/20px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  color: #eee;
  background: #353535;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 600px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 20%;
  height: auto;
}

#countdown {
  width: 465px;
  height: 112px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #222;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #222, #333, #333, #222);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #222, #333, #333, #222);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #222, #333, #333, #222);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #222, #333, #333, #222);
  border: 1px solid #111;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  margin: auto;
  padding: 24px 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

#countdown:before {
  content: "";
  width: 8px;
  height: 65px;
  background: #444;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #555, #444, #444, #555);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #555, #444, #444, #555);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #555, #444, #444, #555);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #555, #444, #444, #555);
  border: 1px solid #111;
  border-top-left-radius: 6px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 48px;
  left: -10px;
}

#countdown:after {
  content: "";
  width: 8px;
  height: 65px;
  background: #444;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #555, #444, #444, #555);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #555, #444, #444, #555);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #555, #444, #444, #555);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #555, #444, #444, #555);
  border: 1px solid #111;
  border-top-right-radius: 6px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 48px;
  right: -10px;
}

#countdown #tiles {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

#countdown #tiles>span {
  width: 92px;
  max-width: 92px;
  font: bold 48px 'Droid Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  color: #111;
  background-color: #ddd;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #bbb, #eee);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #bbb, #eee);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #bbb, #eee);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #bbb, #eee);
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  margin: 0 7px;
  padding: 18px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

#countdown #tiles>span:before {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 13px;
  background: #111;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 3px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 41%;
  left: -3px;
  z-index: -1;
}

#countdown #tiles>span:after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background: #eee;
  border-top: 1px solid #333;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 48%;
  left: 0;
}

#countdown .labels {
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
}

#countdown .labels li {
  width: 102px;
  font: bold 15px 'Droid Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #f47321;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #000;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="countdown">
  <div id='tiles'></div>
  <div class="labels">
    <li>Days</li>
    <li>Hours</li>
    <li>Mins</li>
    <li>Secs</li>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you post the GitHub link with original image assets?

Comment: https://github.com/mihaela1108/front-end/blob/master/logo.png

Comment: https://theketan2.github.io/countdown_site/
repo: https://github.com/TheKetan2/countdown_site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's from the `position: absolute` of many of your html elements. To center it you will need to use something else like `flexbox`:

```js
var target_date = new Date("January 20, 2020");
var days, hours, minutes, seconds; // variables for time units

var countdown = document.getElementById("tiles"); // get tag element

getCountdown();

setInterval(function () { getCountdown(); }, 1000);

function getCountdown(){

    // find the amount of "seconds" between now and target
    var current_date = new Date().getTime();
    var seconds_left = (target_date - current_date) / 1000;

    days = pad( parseInt(seconds_left / 86400) );
    seconds_left = seconds_left % 86400;

    hours = pad( parseInt(seconds_left / 3600) );
    seconds_left = seconds_left % 3600;

    minutes = pad( parseInt(seconds_left / 60) );
    seconds = pad( parseInt( seconds_left % 60 ) );

    // format countdown string + set tag value
    countdown.innerHTML = "<span>" + days + "</span><span>" + hours + "</span><span>" + minutes + "</span><span>" + seconds + "</span>"; 
}

function pad(n) {
    return (n < 10 ? '0' : '') + n;
}
```

```css
body{ 
    font: normal 13px/20px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; word-wrap:break-word;
    color: #eee;
    background: #353535;
}
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

img {
  width: 20%;
}

#countdown{
    width: 465px;
    height: 112px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #222;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #222, #333, #333, #222); 
    background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #222, #333, #333, #222);
    background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, #222, #333, #333, #222);
    background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #222, #333, #333, #222);
    border: 1px solid #111;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    margin: auto;
    padding: 24px 0;
  top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
}

#countdown:before{
    content:"";
    width: 8px;
    height: 65px;
    background: #444;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #555, #444, #444, #555); 
    background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #555, #444, #444, #555);
    background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, #555, #444, #444, #555);
    background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #555, #444, #444, #555);
    border: 1px solid #111;
    border-top-left-radius: 6px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 48px; left: -10px;
}

#countdown:after{
    content:"";
    width: 8px;
    height: 65px;
    background: #444;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #555, #444, #444, #555); 
    background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #555, #444, #444, #555);
    background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, #555, #444, #444, #555);
    background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #555, #444, #444, #555);
    border: 1px solid #111;
    border-top-right-radius: 6px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 48px; right: -10px;
}

#countdown #tiles{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

#countdown #tiles > span{
    width: 92px;
    max-width: 92px;
    font: bold 48px 'Droid Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    color: #111;
    background-color: #ddd;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #bbb, #eee); 
    background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #bbb, #eee);
    background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, #bbb, #eee);
    background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #bbb, #eee);
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    margin: 0 7px;
    padding: 18px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

#countdown #tiles > span:before{
    content:"";
    width: 100%;
    height: 13px;
    background: #111;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 3px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 41%; left: -3px;
    z-index: -1;
}

#countdown #tiles > span:after{
    content:"";
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    background: #eee;
    border-top: 1px solid #333;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 48%; left: 0;
}

#countdown .labels{
    width: 100%;
    height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    bottom: 8px;
}

#countdown .labels li{
    width: 102px;
    font: bold 15px 'Droid Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #f47321;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #000;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <img class="image" src="https://s1.qwant.com/thumbr/700x0/8/a/6d6382c35071b7100be19391aa6d2a6c92664e639146363c7ed5e0458a3c0d/800px-TEE-Logo.svg.png?u=https%3A%2F%2Fupload.wikimedia.org%2Fwikipedia%2Fcommons%2Fthumb%2Ff%2Ff8%2FTEE-Logo.svg%2F800px-TEE-Logo.svg.png&q=0&b=1&p=0&a=1"/>
<div id="countdown">
  <div id='tiles'></div>
  <div class="labels">
    <li>Days</li>
    <li>Hours</li>
    <li>Mins</li>
    <li>Secs</li>
  </div>
</div>
</section>
```

Has you can see your logo and your counter have to be in a same html parent `section` that have a `display: flex` rule.

Comment: it worked for the centered part, but it is not responsive :( here is how it looks like if I make the page smaller: https://github.com/mihaela1108/front-end/blob/master/after.JPG

Comment: thank you, I added the edit and it is perfect now !!

Comment: @Maria1995 Not a problem. Can you please `validate` my answer ? Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code which is also responsive:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="no-js">
  <!--<![endif]-->
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;">
      <div>
        <img src="logo.png" />
      </div>
      <div id="countdown">
        <div id="tiles"></div>
        <div class="labels">
          <li>Days</li>
          <li>Hours</li>
          <li>Mins</li>
          <li>Secs</li>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script>
      var target_date = new Date("January 20, 2020");
      var days, hours, minutes, seconds; // variables for time units
      var countdown = document.getElementById("tiles"); // get tag element
      getCountdown();
      setInterval(function() {
        getCountdown();
      }, 1000);

      function getCountdown() {
        // find the amount of "seconds" between now and target
        var current_date = new Date().getTime();
        var seconds_left = (target_date - current_date) / 1000;
        days = pad(parseInt(seconds_left / 86400));
        seconds_left = seconds_left % 86400;
        hours = pad(parseInt(seconds_left / 3600));
        seconds_left = seconds_left % 3600;
        minutes = pad(parseInt(seconds_left / 60));
        seconds = pad(parseInt(seconds_left % 60));
        // format countdown string + set tag value
        countdown.innerHTML =
          "<span>" +
          days +
          "</span><span>" +
          hours +
          "</span><span>" +
          minutes +
          "</span><span>" +
          seconds +
          "</span>";
      }

      function pad(n) {
        return (n < 10 ? "0" : "") + n;
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
body {
  font: normal 13px/20px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  color: #eee;
  background: #353535;
}

img {
  width: 230px;
  height: auto;
}

#countdown {
  width: 465px;
  height: 112px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #222;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #222, #333, #333, #222);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #222, #333, #333, #222);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #222, #333, #333, #222);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #222, #333, #333, #222);
  border: 1px solid #111;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  margin: auto;
  padding: 24px 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

#countdown:before {
  content: "";
  width: 8px;
  height: 65px;
  background: #444;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #555, #444, #444, #555);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #555, #444, #444, #555);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #555, #444, #444, #555);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #555, #444, #444, #555);
  border: 1px solid #111;
  border-top-left-radius: 6px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 48px;
  left: -10px;
}

#countdown:after {
  content: "";
  width: 8px;
  height: 65px;
  background: #444;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #555, #444, #444, #555);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #555, #444, #444, #555);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #555, #444, #444, #555);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #555, #444, #444, #555);
  border: 1px solid #111;
  border-top-right-radius: 6px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 48px;
  right: -10px;
}

#countdown #tiles {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

#countdown #tiles > span {
  width: 92px;
  max-width: 92px;
  font: bold 48px "Droid Sans", Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  color: #111;
  background-color: #ddd;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #bbb, #eee);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #bbb, #eee);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #bbb, #eee);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #bbb, #eee);
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  margin: 0 7px;
  padding: 18px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

#countdown #tiles > span:before {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 13px;
  background: #111;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 3px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 41%;
  left: -3px;
  z-index: -1;
}

#countdown #tiles > span:after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background: #eee;
  border-top: 1px solid #333;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 48%;
  left: 0;
}

#countdown .labels {
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
}

#countdown .labels li {
  width: 102px;
  font: bold 15px "Droid Sans", Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #f47321;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #000;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

site: [demo](https://theketan2.github.io/countdown_site/)